# Filtering by 2 separate condiitions in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a brand under which two separate campaigns are currently running and so we have two separate tables for each campaign. I want to merge the data in both to bring together the total number of IDs captured from both campaigns.

I am trying to use the below, but it's not filtering by that specific brand and instead is giving me a higher count of IDs because it is including another brand data as well.

````
Select distinct(C_id), brand, campaign, email, from TableCampaign1
UNION ALL
Select distinct(C_id), brand, campaign, email, from TableCampaign2
Where brand = 'XY' AND (campaign IN ('CampaignName1', 'CampaignName2'))```

**I also tried JOIN**. **But with this, I am getting incorrect data. It is showing the data for other campaigns than the two I want to see, plus it's also taking another brand. I am fine to see duplicate values, but I need to get the data only for brand XY and CampaignName1 and CampaignName2**

``` select t1.id as id, t1.email as Email, t1.purpose as Purpose
t1.brand as Brand_name, t1.campaign, t2.campaign, t2.activation as Active,
From Table1 t1
Outer Join Table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
Where t1.campaign = 'CampaigName1' OR t2.campaign = 'CampaignName2' ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add that where clause for the first select too. right now your conditions are applied only to the second one. so it should be something like this:

```
Select distinct(C_id), brand, campaign, email, from TableCampaign1
Where brand = 'XY' AND (campaign IN ('CampaignName1', 'CampaignName2'))
UNION ALL
Select distinct(C_id), brand, campaign, email, from TableCampaign2
Where brand = 'XY' AND (campaign IN ('CampaignName1', 'CampaignName2'))
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Just that I added only the relevant campaign name as per the table in each Select statement.

Comment: I didn't know your exact query. Glad that it helped!